# Can not get relative template url to work in Angular 2 with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack-2

So after several days of trying out each tutorial and article I could find, I still find myself at an impasse trying to get component relative urls to work in my angular2 application.
I'm using webpack 2, and according to the angular documentation, when creating my component I should be able to just do :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'language-selector',
    templateUrl: './language-selector.html',
    styles: ["./language-selector.less"]
})
```

However I get the following errors:

[image]

The relative style works perfectly. The `.html` is located in the same folder as the `.ts` and `.less` files. Any help would be much appreciated!

David

My webpack.config.js:

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.ts',
  watch: false,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: "**/*.{js,ts}",
    aggregateTimeout: 0,
    poll: 10
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: "app.bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'ts-loader'
        ]
      },
       {
        test: /\.less$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
  },

};
```

As for the .html it's just a simple dropdown list with data from a service, that works with an absolute URL.

Comment: you should probably post your webpack config file

Comment: and the `language-selector.html` as well...

Comment: edited the post with the webpack.config, the .html is just a simple dropdown that works perfectly fine with an absolute URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I managed to solve my problem, just in case it could help anyone.
After trying out the suggestions above, I noticed that my I was using Typescript ~1.8, and most guides that recommended using

```
template: require('./language-selector.html')
```

were using ^2.0, so I upgraded typescript, and after I added

```
  "types": ["node"]
```

to my tsconfig.json, I was able to do component relative template urls with the above syntax, using 'require'.

For reference, here's how the header of my component ended up looking like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'language-selector',
    template: require('./language-selector.html'),
    styles: ["./language-selector.less"]
})
```

Thanks for the help! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should add more loaders to parse the angular code and extract the html file:

```
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: ['html-loader']
  }
```

You obviously have to install these loaders using npm. Another option would be to just port your project to use the `angular-cli`, where all these troublesome loader stuff is handled by the cli. As well as packaging and minifying it.

if you do not want that, angular has a [starters guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) to use webpack

Comment: adding more loaders does the same thing, and I did refer to the starters guide when I was editing the webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

add moduleId = module.id in component decorator like this

```
@Component({
 moduleId = module.id,
 selector: 'language-selector',
 templateUrl: './language-selector.html',
 styles: ["./language-selector.less"]
})
```

angular uses it for module-relative loading